# CS50 finance lookup returning 200 none on valid input

Tags: python, api, cs50, finance

I am stuck trying to get my flask input function to work. I am trying to complete the CS50 2020 finance problem. Documentation for the problem can be found [here](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/tracks/web/finance/). The code block bellow is the error message I get in the console when I try to use the index function is run. The api key I am using is valid and when inserting the whole url for the get request I get the expected information. Code may be somewhat messy, I have not cleaned it up and optimized it yet, because I can't get it to work.

```
DEBUG: SELECT quantity FROM oStocks WHERE userID = 5 AND stock = 'AAPL'
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): cloud.iexapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://cloud.iexapis.com:443 "GET /stable/stock/GOOGL-AF/quote?token=<MY_API_KEY> HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

I have tried all I could think of to try and fix this error. changed and unchanged nearly everything about the lookup function. I can't seem to find what is wrong. Can someone please point me in the right direction. Thank you

flask index:

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    userid = session["user_id"]
    owned = db.execute("SELECT stock FROM oStocks WHERE userID = :userid", userid=userid)
    OwnedStocks = []
    for row in owned:
        OwnedStocks.append(row["stock"])

    stockInfo = {}
    for item in OwnedStocks:
        itemInfo = lookup(item)
        tmpQuantity = db.execute("SELECT quantity FROM oStocks WHERE userID = :userid AND stock = :stock", userid=userid, stock=item)
        quantity = tmpQuantity[0]["quantity"]
        sharePrice = itemInfo["price"]
        name = itemInfo["name"]
        value = quantity * sharePrice

        stockInfo[item] = {}
        stockInfo[item]['symbol'] = item
        stockInfo[item]['name'] = name
        stockInfo[item]['shares'] = quantity
        stockInfo[item]['price'] = sharePrice
        stockInfo[item]['value'] = value
    return render_template("portfolio.html", stocks=stockInfo)
```

Lookup Function:

```
def lookup(symbol):
    """Look up quote for symbol."""

    # Contact API
    try:
        api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY")
        response = requests.get(f"https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/{urllib.parse.quote_plus(symbol)}/quote?token={api_key}")
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.RequestException:
        return None

    # Parse response
    try:
        quote = response.json()
        return {
            "name": quote["companyName"],
            "price": float(quote["latestPrice"]),
            "symbol": quote["symbol"]
        }
    except (KeyError, TypeError, ValueError):
        return None
```

Portfolio html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Portfolio
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<div>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr class="font-weight-bold">
          <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Shares</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
          <th scope="col">Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for stock in stocks %}
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ stock['symbol'] }}</th>
            <td>{{ stock['name'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ stock['shares'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ stock['price'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ stock['total'] }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}

      </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please note that you have just revealed your API key. You should revoke/delete it and create a new one. I recommend you never put API keys in your code, but provide them as environment variables or in a config file so that they never get committed/submitted anywhere.

Comment: I just realised you already followed that best practice, but nethertheless, your debug message contains the API key.

Comment: Where is the actual problem? The debug lines you have posted show that everything is fine with that request. `lookup` seems to be working. That said, if there is a problem `lookup` will return `None` which your code that calls `lookup` does not handle.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I just removed my api key from the debug message. The odd thing is it reports HTTP code 200 for successful but the lookup function also returns none as if the request was not successful. When trying to reference `quote=lookup(symbol)` `price = quote['price']` I get the error `messageTypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` for the line attempting to initialize and set price.

Comment: Thank you for helping! your comments helped me get on the right track. When you said 
"Where is the actual problem?" that helped me reevaluate where my problem might really lie. I don't know how I didn't really consider it to be in my template. I learned my lesson.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, now finding it I feel dumb having looked in all the wrong places so long. My mistake was in iterating and calling values from a dictionary passed into a flask template. After much search I ended up realizing and fixing my problem while going through [camposha](https://camposha.info/python-flask-render-dict-from-python-to-jinja2-template/).

My original method was:

```
{% for stock in stocks %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ stock['symbol'] }}</th>
        <td>{{ stock['name'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock['shares'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock['price'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock['total'] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

However the proper way to achieve my goal was:

```
{% for stock, value in stocks.items() %}
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ value['symbol']['stock'] }}</th>
    <td>{{ value['name'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ value['shares'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ value['price'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ value['value'] }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I aslo made some adjustments to my index:

```
def index():
    userid = session["user_id"]
    owned = db.execute("SELECT stock, quantity FROM oStocks WHERE userID = :userid", userid=userid)

    stockInfo = {}
    for item in owned:
        print(item)
        itemInfo = lookup(item['stock'])
        quantity = item['quantity']
        name = itemInfo['name']
        sharePrice = float(itemInfo['price'])
        value = quantity * sharePrice

        stockInfo[item['stock']] = {}
        stockInfo[item['stock']]['symbol'] = item
        stockInfo[item['stock']]['name'] = name
        stockInfo[item['stock']]['shares'] = quantity
        stockInfo[item['stock']]['price'] = sharePrice
        stockInfo[item['stock']]['value'] = value
    return render_template("portfolio.html", stocks=stockInfo)
```